# Prove that two subspaces of a vector space intersect only at 0

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ & $W \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ with set of basis $S_V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ and $S_W=\{w_1,w_2,...,w_m\}$.
The vector space spanned by these basis vectors is the direct sum of $V$ and $W$ with a dimension of $n+m$.

How do I prove that $V \cap W=\{0\}$?

I understand how to draw it conceptually because the only intersection that both subsets share is the zero vector. But I don't quite know how to do the proof mathematically.

Comment: What definition do you use for direct sums?

Comment: Doesn't it follow directly from definition of direct sum?

Comment: How can we sum subspaces of different vector spaces ?

Comment: Think about the dimension of the direct sum. If the intersection had anything else in it....

Comment: I gave it a shot below, any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, everyone. This is what I came up with:
$\forall u \in \mathbb{R}^{m+n}, u=v_i \in V \lor u=w_i \in W$
Therefore, because of the definition of the direct sum and subspaces, we know that $u_i \neq v_i \land u_i \neq w_i$ unless $u_i=0$ therefore $V \cap W = \{0\}$.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct though, feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $u$ is not equal to $v_i$ or $w_i$ but instead a linear combination of the $v_i, w_i$. Put differently y, you could write $u = v + w$, where $v \in V, w \ in W$  

Assume that some vector $v$ is in both $V$ and $W$; try and use the linear independence of $\{v_1, …, v_n, w_1, …, w_m\}$ to conclude that $v = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of different vector spaces, so $V\cap W=\emptyset$. But we can try to make the question meaningful by introducing the maps
\begin{align}
F\colon V\subset\mathbf{R}^m&\to\mathbf{R}^{m+n}\\
v&\mapsto(v,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n\text{ copies}})
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
G\colon W\subset\mathbf{R}^n&\to\mathbf{R}^{m+n}\\
w&\mapsto(\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{m\text{ copies}},w)
\end{align}
$F$ and $G$ are injective and if we define $V':=F(V)\subset\mathbf{R}^{n+m}$ and $W':=G(W)\subset\mathbf{R}^{n+m}$, the maps $V\ni v\mapsto F(v)\in V'$ and $W\ni w\mapsto G(w)\in W'$ are vector space isomorphisms. You can easily prove that $V'\cap W'=\{0\}$ and if $V$ and $W$ span $\mathbf{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{R}^n$, respectively, then $\mathbf{R}^{n+m}=V'\oplus W'$.